# preg_match not working in php when count result return

Tags: php

I have a sample text:

```
$text = "ác, def ác ghi ác xyz ác, jkl";
$search = "ác";
$_x_word = '/(\s)'.$search.'(\s)/i';
preg_match($_x_word, $text, $match_words);
echo count($match_words);
```

When i echo count($match_words) is result return is null

How to fix it output is 2

Comment: http://ideone.com/KbkII --- are you sure you've tried to run it?

Comment: ps: use `var_dump($match_words);`

Comment: @zerkms: var_dump($match_words) => empty

Comment: I've made comprehensive answer with all explanations

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it:

`echo \preg_match_all('/\sác\s/i', "ác, def ác ghi ác xyz ác, jkl");`

Comment: What does the wrapping the `\s` in parenthesis do in this example?

Answer (score 0):

First, when you do this, always use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) around `$search` to escape your regex delimiter.

Then, your code is perfectly fine (even without `preg_quote`). It outputs 3 for me. You may have file encoding issue due to non-ASCII characters in your string. Have you tried using UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$text = "ghi ác xyz ác, jkl";
$search = "ác";
$_x_word = '/\s(' . preg_quote($search) . ')\s/i';
preg_match_all($_x_word, $text, $match_words);
var_dump($match_words);
```

http://ideone.com/hZD3X

Changes I've done:

1. Removed parentheses around `\s` - you don't need matches of whitespaces
2. Added matching group for `$search` (parentheses around)
3. Added `preg_quote`
4. Introduced `var_dump`
5. Changed `preg_match` to `preg_match_all`

PS: probably `\b` instead of `\s` would be better to use

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
preg_match_all($_x_word, $text, $match_words, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

instead of your `preg_match`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `preg_match_all` with `/u` modified for unicode matching to end, And change the paranthesis to get the real matches.

```
<?php
    $text = "ác, def ác ghi ác xyz ác, jkl";
    $search = "ác";
    $_x_word = '/\s('.$search.')\s/ui';
    preg_match_all($_x_word, $text, $match_words);

    //full matches (with spaces)
    var_dump($match_words[0]);
    //only  ác matches.
    var_dump($match_words[1]);
```